# jQuery .height sets to 1724 on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, css, iphone, mobile-safari

i have the following problem: when I use jQuery's `.height()` to set the height of my web page, it sets it to 1742px on an iPhone 5s when in portrait mode. When in landscape mode on a iPad, it is too short!

### CSS

```
html
{
    height:0;
}
input, button
{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

#title
{
    position:relative;
    color:#fafafa;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    top: 7px;
    width:100%;
    height:32px;
    font-weight:800;
}
.container
{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.header
{
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.body-container
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.sideBarIcon
{
    color:#d3d3d3;
    font-weight:lighter;
    position:relative;
}
.nav-container
{
    width:100%;
    height:32px;
}
#sidebb
{
    float:right;
    background-color:#000;
    border:0; 
    margin:0;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
}
#sidemenu
{
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;
}
.sidebar
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#sideBarApear
{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    background:#000;
}
ul, li
{
    display:none;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

js/jQuery

```
var sideBarOpen = false;
var swidth = $(window).width();
var sheight = $(window).height();
$("html").animate({height: (sheight)});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sidebb").click(function(){
        if (sideBarOpen === false)
        {
            $("#sideBarApear").animate({height: (sheight-50)+"px",width: (swidth/100*15)+"px"});
            sideBarOpen = true;
        }else {
            $("#sideBarApear").animate({height:'30px',width:'30px'});
            sideBarOpen = false;
        }
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>insert title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mobile.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="MobileJs.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
    </head>

    <body class="container">

        <div class="header">
            <div class="nav-container">
                <h1 id="title">Click the button</h1>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body-container">
            <div id="sidemenu">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <div id="sideBarApear">
                        <button id="sidebb">
                            <i class="fa fa-list fa-lg sideBarIcon"></i>
                        </button>
                        <ul>
                            <li>12</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[live example](http://clickthebutton.esy.es/CTBM)

I just can't seem to figure this out...

...help would be much apreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're defining sHeight and sWidth before the document is ready. If you wait until the document is ready, you will be able to get accurate measures for height.

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var sideBarOpen = false;
var swidth = $(window).width();
var sheight = $(window).height();

$("html").animate({height: (sheight)});
    $("#sidebb").click(function(){
        if (sideBarOpen === false)
        {
            $("#sideBarApear").animate({height: (sheight-50)+"px",width: (swidth/100*15)+"px"});
            sideBarOpen = true;
        }else {
            $("#sideBarApear").animate({height:'30px',width:'30px'});
            sideBarOpen = false;
        }
    });
});
```